# Inbuilt flash memory size not enough

Tags: microcontroller, programming, memory, flash, eeprom

I am using TM4C1230C3PMI controller from Texas instrument in one of my project. It has 32KB of internal flash, which is not sufficient for my application. Higher flash sized micro-controller are available in the market which can be used but I want to go with this micro-controller only. As per my knowledge external EEPROM can be used to increase the total flash size (Program memory).

Is my thinking is correct?

If not please suggest how can I increase the total flash memory size of the controller?

Comment: External EEPROM is typically used for storing data because the internal Flash allows less erase/write cycles then most EEPROMs and it can be overwritten byte-wise. For CPUs with an external bus interface (your one does not have this) it would be possible to add external program memory (however this is a bit complicated...). Theoretically it would be possible to store pieces of code in an external EEPROM and to load this code into RAM to execute it - however in most cases this scenario is not realistic.

Comment: Many years ago, a related maxim was "If you can't do it in 1K, you can't do it." I thought it was clever and worth thinking about, but didn't really accept it. Then MicroChess arrived in 1K.

Comment: Why dont you boot your code from an external memory? There are a number of external memories that can be interfaced to your uC. This will not place constraints on your internal flash as you will be booting your code externally.

Comment: [What are some refactoring methods to reduce size of compiled code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/662439/995714), [How to Reduce Code Size (and Memory Cost) Without Sacrificing Performance](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4006490/How-to-Reduce-Code-Size-and-Memory-Cost-Without-Sacrificing-Performance), [How to reduce program size](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=112878.0), [Writing Efficient C and C Code Optimization](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6154/Writing-Efficient-C-and-C-Code-Optimization)

Comment: [Code size optimization forembedded processors](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-607.pdf)

Comment: @Akshay I think you have answered my question. I was expecting a answer something similar as you commented.My question was whether an external memory can be used to increase the total program memory of the MCU.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You cannot extend the program memory (flash).  TI produces the same chip with double the flash and RAM, but nothing else changed: *TM4C1230D5PMI*.

If you cannot use a chip with larger flash, you will have to reduce your code size:

- Disable debugging, such as the expensive `printf` function.  A `printf` that supports floating point output will typically set you back around 5KB-10KB.
- Make sure you compile with optimization enabled - typically the compiler flag is `-Os`.
- Modern compilers can do *link time optimization (LTO)*.  With gcc, you get this with `-flto`.  You have to pass `-flto` to both compilation and link stages, for all files.  This typically reduces the produced code size by 30%-50%.

Answer (score 2):

You might get the smallest software footprint by using assembler and a Forth-like language designed for your purpose. Another is compressed machine code if there is a lot of almost identical code.